# Retrieve another field whose row is selected by an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT a.first_field, min(a.second_field), X 
FROM a
GROUP BY (a.first_field)
```

I want **X** to be **a.third_field** from the row that is selected by **min(a.second_field)**
How do I do that?

Detailed explanation:

**min(a.second_field)** retrieves one minimum value from values (from rows) that are grouped by **a.first_field**.
The value that is retrieved has to come from **a row** right? I want the query to also return **another field** value from **the row** that is selected by **min function**. Not only the minimum value of the field which is processed by **min function**.

Comment: I am not getting your point can you show your data structure?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate using an example.

Comment: I've added some details

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get field value from a record that causes an aggregate condition to be true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541854/get-field-value-from-a-record-that-causes-an-aggregate-condition-to-be-true)

Comment: @Clodoaldo It's different, similar but different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html)

```
select first_field,second_field,third_field
from
(
SELECT a.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER (PARTITION BY a.first_field  
               ORDER BY second_field) 
        as rn
FROM a
) b where b.rn=1;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ad740/4)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to find **third_value** from row with minimum value of **second_field**. Then use this:

```
SELECT a.first_field, a.second_field, a.third_field
FROM a
WHERE a.third_field = MIN(a.third_field)
GROUP BY a.first_field
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT b.*, min(a.third_field) FROM (
SELECT a.first_field, min(a.second_field) 
FROM a
GROUP BY (a.first_field) ) as b
INNER JOIN a
```

Poorly formatted but it should work