# Find values from row where some column meets an aggregate condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL SERVER 2008 R2. Two tables having a 1-many relationship, and want some fields from both, but on the many side, only values from a certain row.  That row is specified by some condition, in my case it should the row having the smallest ClaimId for that PaymentId.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Payments') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Payments
CREATE TABLE #Payments ( PaymentId int UNIQUE NOT NULL )
INSERT INTO #Payments ( PaymentId )
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Claims') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Claims
CREATE TABLE #Claims ( PaymentId int NOT NULL, ClaimId int NOT NULL, FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL )
INSERT INTO #Claims ( PaymentId, ClaimId, FirstName )
VALUES (1, 51,'Joe'), (1, 57,'Jane'), (2, 62,'Spot'), (2, 63,'Rover'), (3, 88,'Sue'), (3, 89,'Sally')

SELECT * FROM #Payments p
JOIN #Claims c ON p.PaymentId=c.PaymentId
WHERE c.ClaimId=MIN(ClaimId)
GROUP BY p.PaymentId
HAVING MIN(ClaimId)
```

The desired result is as follows, where the claim is from the row having the minimum claimId for a given paymentId.  ClaimId may not be ordered, so seeking minimum, not first.

```
PaymentId   ClaimId   FirstName
1           51        Joe
2           62        Spot
3           88        Sue
```

I'd be happy to refer to an existing question/answer, but don't know how to word this that I find something similar.  Perhaps [Get field value from a record that causes an aggregate condition to be true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541854/get-field-value-from-a-record-that-causes-an-aggregate-condition-to-be-true) but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, I like to use `outer apply` for this:

```
select p.*, c.*
from #Payments p outer apply
     (select top 1 c.*
      from #Claims c
      where c.paymentid = p.paymentid
      order by c.claimid
     ) c;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function like this:

```
SELECT PaymentId, ClaimId, FirstName
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        p.PaymentId, 
        c.ClaimId, 
        c.FirstName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.PaymentId ORDER BY c.ClaimId) as RN 
    FROM #Payments p
    JOIN #Claims c ON p.PaymentId=c.PaymentId
) as T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

solution using `RANK()`

```
;WITH A
    AS (SELECT p.PaymentId
            , c.ClaimId
            , c.FirstName
            , rn = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY P.PaymentId ORDER BY ClaimId ASC)
        FROM   #Payments p
             JOIN #Claims c ON p.PaymentId = c.PaymentId)
    SELECT PaymentId
        , ClaimId
        , FirstName
    FROM   A
    WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use windows function row_number to provide an order

```
;with cte as
(
select PaymentID, ClaimID, row_number() over (partition by PaymentID order by ClaimID ) as rn
from #Claims
)

select p.*,cte.ClaimID
from #Payments p
join cte on cte.paymentID = p.paymentID
where rn=1 --limits to earliest claimid
```

Comment: Looks like we all solved it at the same time with roughly the same approach.

Comment: @disassemble-number-5 The advantage to these approaches is that you can take as many columns from the detail table as you need. I see that you mentioned that in McNets answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences return same result, first one select MIN(ClaimId) for every PaymentId:

```
SELECT P.*, C.*
FROM #Payments P
    INNER JOIN #Claims C ON C.PaymentId = P.PaymentId
WHERE C.ClaimID IN (SELECT MIN(ClaimID) OVER (PARTITION BY PaymentId) FROM #Claims);
```

Second uses a CTE to find MIN(ClaimId) before to join to Payments table:cº

```
WITH PY AS
(
    SELECT PaymentId, MIN(ClaimId) as ClaimID
    FROM #Claims
    GROUP BY PaymentId
)
SELECT PY.PayMentId, PY.ClaimId, C.FirstName, P.*
FROM PY
     LEFT JOIN #Claims c ON p.ClaimId = c.ClaimId;
     LEFT JOIN #Payments P ON P.PaymentId = PY.PaymentId


+-----------+---------+-----------+
| PayMentId | ClaimId | FirstName |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 1         | 51      | Joe       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2         | 62      | Spot      |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 3         | 88      | Sue       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/KRT45653

Comment: There are other things I'm getting from payments, just didn't want to clutter up the question with those fields.